# How can i fix my java code for rock paper scissors?

Tags: java

```
package rps;


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rps
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int rock, paper, scissors;
    int compa;
    String Computer;
    String Human;


 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
 Human= keyboard.nextLine();
 System.out.println("You chose");
 System.out.println(Human);

 try
 {
  int HC = Integer.parseInt(Human.trim()); // i know this part is wrong
 }
 catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
 {

 Random generator = new Random();
 compa=generator.nextInt(3);

 switch(compa){
       case 0:
       rock=0;
       System.out.println("I choose Rock");
        if (Human.equals(2));
       System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors, i win");
         if(Human.equals(0));
 System.out.println("You must be psychic, i chose rock too!");

       if (Human.equals(1));
 System.out.println("paper covers rock, you lost");
 break;

        case 1:
         paper=1;
        System.out.println("I chose paper");
        if (Human.equals(0));
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock, you lose");
        if (Human.equals(1));
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        if (Human.equals(2));
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock, i lost");
        break;
    case 2:
        scissors=2;
        System.out.println("I chose scissors");
        if (Human.equals(1));
  System.out.println("scissors cut through paper, i win.");
        if (Human.equals(2));
  System.out.println("We both chose scissors");
        if (Human.equals(0));
  System.out.println("Rock smashed scissors, i lost");
  break;


        }
  }
```

I want to convert the string Human into an integer which is what my instructor told me to do before i inserted the try/catch

Since Human isn't a value like (123) i figure the try catch would work for the number format exception.

in my original code i didn't use HC as the variable i continued to use Human
but it still listed all the answers instead of comparing human to the computer

Comment: First of all, your `if` statements are broken. `if` statements need to have their bodies surrounded by `{` and `}`. Like this: `if (1 + 1 == 2) { return 2; }`. No semicolons near the `if` section, only in the body (`return 2;`). Try taking a look at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java) to supplement your learning in school. Or if you have been assigned a text book, you might want to refer to it more often. You also might have tutoring resources available to you. Fixing the existing issues in your program might help you solve the question you have.

Comment: In above code Why are you using switch in catch block and all you code below the catch in catch block since you are not closing it..

Answer (score 2):

There are two big errors on this line, and on many similar lines in your code:

```
if (Human.equals(2));
```

The first error is that the semicolon is wrong.  Java (like C and other languages) has an "empty" statement that is just a semicolon with nothing else, and it does nothing.  What you've actually done is

```
if (Human.equals(2)) 
    /* do nothing */ ;
System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors, i win");
```

The `if` has no effect, and the `println` happens no matter whether the `if` is true or not.  Get rid of the semicolon.  Also, it's best to get in the habit of always using curly braces for the body of the `if`, like

```
if (Humans.equals(2)) {
    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors, i win");
}
```

Java doesn't require the braces, but it's best to use them always.  Some companies and style checkers do require the braces.  And they help prevent errors that come up when you think a statement is part of an `if` and it isn't.

The second is that you're comparing a `String` (`Human`) to an integer (2), which does not work.  This will always return `false`, no matter what `Human` is.  Java will let you compare two objects of different classes, but the result is always `false` unless you've written your own custom `equals` that can compare objects of two different classes (not usually a good idea, except when they're subclasses of the same ancestor class).

It looks like you want to parse the input string as an integer, giving an `int`, and then use the `int` to do your comparisons.  (That's a little confusing to the user, since you haven't told them to enter a number.  But I'll go along with it because it lets me make a couple other important points.)  This is what you tried:

```
try
 {
  int HC = Integer.parseInt(Human.trim()); // i know this part is wrong
 }
 catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
 {
```

The rest of your logic is inside the `catch`, which means it will execute only if `Human` is **not** a valid integer, which probably isn't what you want.  The code in a `catch` block is executed only when the exception happens.  You can fix this by moving the rest of the logic into the `try` block (between the curly braces), and then that code can compare `HC` instead of `Human`, like this:

```
if (HC == 2) {
    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors, i win");
}
```

The other thing you can do is to close the `catch` block earlier.  You could do this:

```
int HC;
try
 {
     HC = Integer.parseInt(Human.trim()); // i know this part is wrong
 }
 catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
 {
     HC = -1;
 }
```

I don't recommend handling exceptions this way, but I did this to make a point.  If you say `int HC = Integer.parseInt(Human.trim());` inside the curly braces of the `try`, *it is visible only within those curly braces*.  Thus, logic that comes below the `catch` block can't see `HC`.  By moving the *declaration* of `HC` outside of those curly braces, it is now visible by the logic after the `catch` block.  So then you could again change `if (Human.equals(2))` to

```
if (HC == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the switch part of your code, looks like you accept user input as integers right?

If that's the case, why not use `nextInt()` to read int input instead of `nextLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the awkward try/catch block, I'd recommend giving the user a menu prompting them to input an integer that you can easily use to compare to your random integer, such as:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Make Selection:");
System.out.println("1) Rock");
System.out.println("2) Paper");
System.out.println("3) Scissors ");
int choice = keyboard.nextInt()-1;
```

If you need to accept a string is part of your assignment, then use the equals method for strings to convert to an integer via if statements.

```
int choice;
string human= keyboard.nextLine();
if(human.equals("Rock")){
    choice = 0;
}else if(human.equals("Paper"){
    choice = 1;
}else if(human.equals("Scissors"){
    choice = 2;
}else{
    System.out.print("Invalid Selection");
}
```

There are other errors in your code (note the comments), but this should at least give you some options to get over the hump of getting the user input into something your program can easily use.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to make note of the issues in your original code that caused some bugs.

1. A closing bracket `}`is missing at the end of your code to close off the class.
2. As was mentioned in the comment, your `if` statements should not have a semicolon at the end of them and should rather have a opening and closing bracket `{}` immediately preceding the if statement. Now that being said you can get away with not using the brackets, but then only the line immediately preceding the `if` statement will be nested under the `if`statement>.
3. The `try...catch` should be used to catch any errors in the program and properly handle them. In the case of your code you are using it to help run the program; this is bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible.

Now as to solving your problem, I cannot see a way to do so using the logic you have shown here. In your algorithm you:

1. Input the user's choice
2. Try to convert a word to a number
3. If it works, assign it to a variable and end the program
4. If it does not work, execute the rest of the code in the program

The error here is that, based on the input you are expecting, you will always fail the `try/catch` and never actually convert the user's input to a number. This causes a bug later on as in your `if` statements are checking the value of `Human` to see if it's a number, which it isn't.

As was mentioned in a different answer you could change the input to accept and expect a number instead of a string (ie. "Enter the number for either: Rock = 0, Paper = 1, Scissors = 2:"). This would take care of the number issue right from the start and help to simplify your code.

Another method to solving it, if you would rather stick to text inputs rather than numbers, would be to include a simple switch to convert the user's input to a number. For example:

```
int humanNumber = -1;
int rock = 0;
int paper = 1;
int scissors = 2;
switch(Human) {
  case 'rock':
    humanNumber = rock;
    break;
  case 'paper':
    humanNumber = paper;
    break;
  case 'scissors':
    humanNumber = scissors;
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Doing this will allow the input to remain as text, convert the text to a number and also handle any unwanted inputs.

The final solution that I would like to suggest using would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2;
    int computer = -1, human = -1;
    String input;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You chose " + input);

    switch(input.toLowerCase()) {
        case "rock":
            human = rock;
            break;
        case "paper":
            human = paper;
            break;
        case "scissors":
            human = scissors;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
    if (human >= 0) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        computer = generator.nextInt(3);
        System.out.println(human + " " + computer);
        switch(computer) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("I chose Rock");
                if (human == scissors)
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors, i win");
                else if (human == rock)
                    System.out.println("You must be psychic, i chose rock too!");
                else
                    System.out.println("paper covers rock, i lost");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("I chose Paper");
                if (human == rock)
                    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, you lose");
                else if (human == paper)
                    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
                else
                    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, i lost");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("I chose scissors");
                if (human == paper)
                    System.out.println("scissors cut through paper, i win.");
                else if (human == scissors)
                    System.out.println("We both chose scissors");
                else
                    System.out.println("Rock smashed scissors, i lost");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```